# RegexpError: Stack overflow in regexp matcher

Tags: ruby, regex

I have small problem with a simple tokenizer regex:

```
def test_tokenizer_regex_limit
   string = '<p>a</p>' * 400
   tokens = string.scan(/(<\s*tag:.*?\/?>)|((?:[^<]|\<(?!\s*tag:.*?\/?>))+)/)
end
```

Basically it runs through the text and gets pairs of [ matched_tag , other_text ]. Here's an example: http://rubular.com/r/f88JBjfzFh

Works fine for smaller sets. If you run in under ruby 1.8.7 it will blow up. 1.9.2 works fine.

Any ideas how to simplify / improve this? My regex-fu is weak

Comment: I'm not really (x)html parsing though. Just need to tokenize text like this:  text | <tag:blah> | more text | <tag:meh>. As a matter of fact it could be a string like this: '<a href="<tag:url>">' Not really parsable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more simplified but not much:

```
(<[^<]*:[^<]*>)|((?:[^<]|<[^:]*>)+)
```

<strike>(<.*?>|[^<>]+)</strike>

Comment: kinda, but not really. I need two capture groups like so: (<.*?>)|([^<>]+) and it's almost there. But! It will match '<not_tag>' into the first group. I need to put tags only of this format <tag:something> everything else should be in the second capture group.

Comment: I updated my solution, but it's not much better than what you already have. I hope you find your answer!